# How to make comments serializer work with post serializer in django rest framework.?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this comment serializer which is not working. It is showing this error

```
{
"post": [
    "This field is required."
]
}
```

I am quite new to this, so can't really figure out how to properly link both the post and comment model.

this is my serializer

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
content = serializers.CharField()
post = PostSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['id', 'post', 'content', 'reply']

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    content = validated_data['content']
    reply = validated_data['reply']
    if reply:
        comment = Comment(user=user, content=content, reply=reply, post=post)
        comment.save()
    else:
        comment = Comment(user=user, content=content, post=post)
        comment.save()
    return validated_data
```

view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def comment_post_api(request, slug):
    try:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = CommentCreateSerializer(post,data=request.data, context={'request':request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls

```
 path('<slug>/comment/', views.comment_post_api, name='comment_post'),
```

Thanks

Comment: you want to create a post with a comment or just want to select an existing post?

Comment: I want to select an existing post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these way:

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.CharField()
    user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='user',queryset=User.objects.all(),write_only=True)
    post_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='post',queryset=Post.objects.all(),write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id', 'post_id','user_id','content', 'reply']
```

and remove you create method not needed because you forgot to add post object creation before assign

or you can just write

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

no need add custom create method here also

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def comment_post_api(request, slug):
    try:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        serializers = CommentCreateSerializer(comments,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CommentCreateSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request':request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't use the default User model, so should I go with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL ?

Comment: Please remove custom create method if you don't want to create user and post from comment creation.

Comment: Ok.I removed the create method. but now when using the first method, it is showing user_id and post_id field is required and while using the second one, it is showing user and post fields are required.

Comment: but you assigned use and post?

Comment: Yes, I followed the exact same thing as you said..may be something is wrong with my views??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218879/discussion-between-pruthvi-barot-and-danny).